# Ansible: How to refer to variables of a specific key

Tags: loops, variables, ansible

I have a `host_vars` file that looks like this:

```
---
clients:
cl1:
  to_install:
  - value11
  - value21
  to_uninstall:
  - value31
cl3:
  to_install:
  - value12
  - value22
  - value32
  to_uninstall:
  - value42
```

I would like the values listed under `cl1/to_install` to be installed to `cl1` client only, and those under `cl3/to_install` to be installed to `cl3` only. This should be done by looping the values contained in `to_install`. cl1 and cl3 are also defined in the hosts file.
I am trying just to print the values:

```
- name: test variables...
  hosts: localhost
  vars_files:
    - path/to/hosts_vars
tasks:
- name: Print softwares to install
  debug: msg="Softwares installed on {{ item.key }} are: {{ item.value.to_install }}"
  with_dict:
    - "{{ clients }}"
```

but this would print `to_install` of both clients. I could also refer to the client explicitly (for example with cl1 in place of key) but the number of clients defined in `host_vars` will change every time. How could I refer to the values in `to_install` of a specific client only? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you are looking something like this:

```
---
clients:
  cl1:
    name: My-First-Machine
    to_install:
      - value11
      - value21
    to_uninstall:
      - value31
  cl3:
    name: My-Second-Machine
    to_install:
    - value12
    - value22
    - value32
    to_uninstall:
    - value42
```

and then in your playbook something like this:

```
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "Softwares installed on {{ clients[machine].name }} are: {{ clients[machine].to_install }}"
```

Then you can use your playbook like this for cl1 machine:

```
ansible-playbook -i hosts test.yml -e "machine=cl1"
```

will give you the result like this:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Softwares installed on My-First-Machine are: [u'value11', u'value21']"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Also you can use your playbook like this for cl3 machine:

```
ansible-playbook -i hosts test.yml -e "machine=cl3"
```

will give you the result like this:

```
PLAY [local] *******************************************************************

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Softwares installed on My-Second-Machine are: [u'value12', u'value22', u'value32']"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Hope that might help you.

Comment: Thanks that surely helps. I was wondering what `-e` stands for when you call the playbook? and if Ieave blank the `name` field, i.e. without `My-first-Machine` will it work too?

Comment: `-e` stand for extra-variable, use this to get the information for specific machine like cl1/cl3 and if you leave the `name` then it will work but show you the complete variable instead of machine name. try it and let me know if you need more help

Comment: It works great! I left the `name` out and I am using just `{{machine}}`, so that prints the name of the client. Thank you again